# React; how to gather user state input and append to new component on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

```
import './App.css';
import GoalBox from './Components/GoalBox';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';



function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const inputReset = useRef(null)

  let arr = [];

  const submitValue = () => {
    const todoList = {
      'todo': value
    }
    console.log(todoList);
    inputReset.current.value = ''; // resets input field
    
    arr.push(todoList)
    console.log('todo array', arr)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List of things to do</h1>
      <input ref={inputReset} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={submitValue}>Add New To do</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So I have a functional component here, and I have useState setting the value of 'value' upon each button click. That works. What doesn't work is getting more than one value into my array. I have tried many ways, more than I want to list...
    I want an array of let's say, 7 items of things to do, which I will then pass as props to  and have THAT component append the DOM with a new card stating the todo items...directly after input submission...
    In vanilla JS I have achieved this simply by using document.createElement('div').innerHTML = `<p>${input.value}</p>` (summarized)
But I cannot figure out how to do this in react...Any help, mainly including where I am misunderstanding React usage, would be oh so great!

Comment: can you please share expected output.

Comment: My expected output is that 'value' is pushed to the array on each button click, and that I actually have more than 'one' item in the array at a time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only re-render will happen when a component state changes.

Instead of using local variables (`let arr = [];`), it should be another react state hook like:

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
```

Then you can add new todos as below:

```
setArr((prevArr) => [...prevArr, todoItem]);
```

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  const inputReset = React.useRef(null);

  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([]);

  const submitValue = () => {
    const todoItem = {
      todo: value
    };
    setArr((prevArr) => [...prevArr, todoItem]);
    inputReset.current.value = ""; // resets input field
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List of things to do</h1>
      <input ref={inputReset} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={submitValue}>Add New To do</button>
      {arr.map(({ todo }) => (
        <div key={todo}>{todo}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: I like how you share a runnable code snippet it's nice !

Comment: @Amila Thanks for pointing this out --> "Only re-render will happen when a component state changes."....I take it that is why the public array was not Holding onto new data I was pushing? This worked great thanks, I passed it into props on a separate component that is a card and mapped it out similar to what you did. Question: why are you mapping with this { todo } object looking format? is there a particular advantage to this vs arr.map(item => item.todo) ??
Either way, thank you for the solution, I appreciate you moving me along. Also, Thomas Zimmermann, I appreciate your solution as well.

Comment: you can use `todo` instead of `item.todo`. That's why. When you have many properties `item.` part becomes redundant

Comment: one less piece of text in the code, and not totally necessary to have...sounds good, I will implement this style more often. Thank you @Amila Senadheera

Answer (score 1):

You can do such task by using React state:

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  const submitValue = () => {
    setValue(""); // resets input field
    setArr([...arr, { todo: value }]); // Use shallow copy to give a new ref
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List of things to do</h1>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={submitValue}>Add New To do</button>
      {arr.map(({todo}) => <p key={todo}>{todo}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```